# ngbuild changing placeholder according to environment

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, ng-build

I have an Angular 5 project. To get the package to deploy, I'm using NG BUILD command. But, I have some placeholders that I need to change accordingly with the environment. For example, I have one configuration file  placeholder. To PROD I need to change the value to http://blablabla.com, and for TEST environment change to http://localhost. I'm sure if using NG BUILD I can do it.

Comment: Add the values into your environment.ts files

Answer (score 1):

In your project Angular 5 you have a directory "environments" like image bellow with 2 files:

[image: Enviroments]

**environment.ts**: This file exports a constant JSON object environment. If you refer environment object properties in your Angular project, during development mode i.e. ng serve or ng build all values shall be read from this file.

**environment.prod.ts**: This file exports same JSON object and should have same properties as of environment.ts file. When you build your application for production mode using ng build --prod in that case, all values of environment.ts file shall get overridden by environment.prod.ts files.

Put development HTTP Url inside environment.ts file

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: 'https://fakerestapi.com/api'  
};
```

Put production HTTP Url inside environment.prod.ts file:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  baseUrl: 'https://production.com/api'
};
```

In rest of Angular application, refer environment.baseUrl

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';


@Injectable()
export class ClientService {  

  baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getClients(): Observable<Client[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Client[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/clients`);
  }
}
```

I hope I helped you.

Comment: It's nice but, how Can I use this same on HTML files as well?

Answer (score 0):

Put your variables in your environment.ts files, so if you have:

**Dev**
environment.dev.ts

etc.. for other environments, wherever you require your variables import environment and use via environment.yourVariable.

Then based on your build command such as; `ng build --prod` it'll use the environment.prod.ts file and it's configs.

Environment file ex:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  animal: ''
};
```